# How to invoke C compiler under gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, arrays, constants

According to my memory the following piece of code should compile fine on C++ but not in C.
Only problem is how to test it? It compiled fine with g++ and also with gcc. I'm assuming that g++ is C++ compiler and gcc is C compiler. I've tried it with mingw under Windows. Am I correct? if not then how to compile it using C compiler.

```
int main() {
 const int i = 1;
 const int j = 2;
 const int k = 3;

 int array[i + j + k];
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put it in a ".c" rather than a ".cpp" file?

Comment: dynamic specification of array length is defined with the c99 specification

Comment: By default, gcc will actually treat the file C++ if the extension is considered a C++ extension (.cpp, .cc, etc) but g++ will always treat the file as C++ even if it has a plain .c extension.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, that will compile in C99, which has support for [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).  To get strict C89 behavior, try compiling with:

```
gcc -std=c89 -pedantic-errors
```

That gives:

```
error: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘array’
```

c89 means use C89, pedantic-errors means error on non-C89 code.

Answer (score 3):

It's legal in recent versions of C, either C99 or gcc extensions. Use the pedantic and standard options to restrict the accepted syntax:

```
peregrino:$ gcc -pedantic -std=c89 src/maybe_pedantic.c 
src/maybe_pedantic.c: In function ‘main’:
src/maybe_pedantic.c:6: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘array’
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter for specifying a language with gcc is `-x`

from `gcc --help` on my system:

```
# -x <language>            Specify the language of the following input files
#                          Permissible languages include: c c++ assembler none
#                          'none' means revert to the default behavior of
#                          guessing the language based on the file's extension
```

However, your code is valid C code.

Answer (score 0):

It will compile in C++ and C99(but not in C89)

> It compiled fine with g++ and also with gcc

gcc supports C99

> if not then how to compile it using C compiler?

Chance the extension of the file from `*.cpp` to `*.c`.

Comment: GCC supports c89 as well. Compile with -ansi or -std=c89 flags.

Comment: compiling without such options defaults to C99.

Comment: Compiling without such option defaults to "GNU C" or "GNU C++", the meaning of which depends upon the version of GCC.